# HW components involved in I/O

Tags: hard-drive, usb, drivers, motherboard

Starting with the CPU, or it's accompanying chipset (ex, Intel PCH), what are the various HW components involved in translating a read/write to disk, and what is their role?

Specifically, I am confused about the roles of the following:

1. Host controller
2. Device controller
3. Host bus adapter

As far as I can tell:

1. Host controller: Circuitry that exists on the motherboard. Includes register-level interface for drivers to interact with. Responsible for translating requests from it's registers into actions: read/writing to attached devices directly. For example, USB. Also may contain DMA ability.
2. Device controller: Same as the host controller, but exists on the
   external device, such as a disc controller on a HDD.
3. Host bus adapter: Translates an external bus protocol to an internal one. Transparent to software. For example, a driver that wants to read/write to registers on an external HDD disc controller HDD connected over SATA or over Infiniband.

How would then, a device such as an external keyboard connected over USB work?At the SW-level, the drivers still appear to be communicating with specific registers; however, there are 2 controllers in play.

Comment: I recommend reading about [Abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)) and the magical powers it can bring to the table. Using abstraction we don't need to worry about how the USB root hub is connected, we just focus on dealing with the USB device, or even just with the fact that it is "_a keyboard_" (at this level, we don't even care that it's connected via USB).

Comment: @Attie But sometimes you want to know how things work.

Comment: Of course! - I'm not suggesting you don't look into it, rather helping to give you related things to read about! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Host controller*, *Host bus adapter* or even *Host adapter* are just different names for the same thing (c.f. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_adapter)): A piece of hardware that connects the bus between the host (your PC) and the device (your external harddisk) to the internal bus (PCIe) of the host.

So, for an harddisk via SATA:

```
<--------- PC --------->         <------ Harddisk ------>

PC south-      SATA host          SATA device       Device
bridge    ---- controller ....... controller   ---- SoC
           ^^               ^^                  ^^
        PCIe-Bus          SATA-Bus        Some kind of bus
```

The host controller can exist on the motherboard, or as a separate card. The PC can read/write to the registers of the host controller, or do DMA, and the host controllers translates these into actions on the SATA-Bus (or translates actions on the SATA-Bus into corresponding register values or DMA actions).

Something like a "host bus adapter" that's transparent to software doesn't exist in this sense, though it's of course possible to design some device that emulates another device (e.g., an USB stick emulates a harddisk, using the same protocol as would be used for a harddisk).

The picture is the same for a keyboard connected via USB:

```
<--------- PC --------->         <------ Keyboard ------>

PC south-      USB host           USB device       Device
bridge    ---- controller ....... controller   ---- SoC
           ^^               ^^                  ^^
        PCIe-Bus          USB-Bus          Internal bus
```

Though here the USB device controller will be integrated on a single chip with the keyboard embedded controller, and the bus is internal and you won't see it when opeing the keyboard.

The software stack in general is more complicated than you describe; there are other protocols or even protocol stacks above the bus protocol itself, e.g. the mentioned "USB storage" protocol (which is similar to SCSI) above the basic USB protocol, or the "USB HID" protocol for the keyboard above the basic USB protocol.

Comment: Specifically for Intel, isn't the notion of a "south bridge" an outdated concept? Looking at the datasheets, it seems many controllers are integrated in the PCH. Since you mentioned Wikipedia, can you reconcile the paragraph that explicitly compares [*disc controller* vs *hba*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_controller)?

Comment: I used "south bridge" because that's a widely known term, call it whatever you want. It's the part where the PCIe root controller sits, or whatever internal bus your PC has. "Disk controller" comes from a time when there was no additional bus (or not something that you'd call "bus") between this piece of hardware and the disk. That slowly evolved into a real bus (and busses slowly evolve into something that works more like a network with packets (PCIe, USB 3.0)), so that part still kept being called "disk controller".

Comment: In the end, all of this are names, it doesn' really matter what you call a piece of hardware, though some people have strong feelings about the "right name" and will edit Wikipedia articles until they are completely confusing. IMHO the names are not important, the hardware is.

Comment: I agree about the naming - once you know how the hardware works. Before then, when trying to learn/find information, the names can help :). OK - would you say then, that for most classes of IO devices, the diagram you drew is sufficient? I.e. 2 controllers, and a shared external bus? Does this mental model apply to SATA, USB, network cards, ect?

Comment: The diagram is *bus centric* - you have some kind of bus, and a bus controller/adapter/whatever you like to call it at both ends. Basically everything you can connect over such a bus (or network) follows this pattern: RS232, I2C, SDI, USB, IDE, PATA, SATA, 802.3 Ethernet, 802.11 WLAN, IEEE 1901 PowerLAN ... Real hardware will possibly have several busses (an I2C chip in a USB device), or be accessible differently (e.g. GPIO). It's a useful pattern, but not complete. I suggest to look at concrete examples (google datasheets) to get a better mental model.

Comment: For the concrete examples, they would be, for example, a google datasheet for a USB stack?

Comment: The USB stack is sufficiently complicated I'd read up on the protocol first. Google e.g. "ehci controller datasheet" to find the Intel spec, complete with registers. You'll probably need at least a week. For contrast, start with something simpler (and outdated), like the [floppy disk controller](http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/study/hardware/Floppy/floppy.htm) (yes, *disk controller*) that used to be attached directly on the ISA bus, and control the floppy directly, which doesn't fit the "two controllers on both sides of a bus" model.

Comment: *"control the floppy directly, which doesn't fit the "two controllers on both sides of a bus" model."* -- You're trying to apply modern topology to old electronics. Floppy drives and HDDs before IDE, e.g. ST506 and SMD, are dumb drives that  have numerous *analog*  interface signals to its disk controller.  The controller existed for the purpose of an all-digital interface for the drive or device.  When electronics got cheap & small & low-powered, then the controller could be embedded with its drive/device.  By then floppys were obsolete, but HDDs became IDE drives.

Comment: @sawdust I am not trying to apply anything to anything. Note the "for contrast", which explicitely says that I don't. What I am saying is that it may help to read up on some detail how things developed, because it's easier to understand in the early stages. And yes, I know how the history went; I've read the datasheets, and I can tell you all the "stack another protocol on another protocol" issues.

Answer (score 1):

This question only:

> How would then, a device such as an external keyboard connected over
>   USB work?

When the device is plugged in windows sends out a please identify your self command, and all USB devices are required to respond to it.

Windows queries its internal databases to look for a driver, and configure the device.  Then the driver takes over responsibility.

Even a simple USB keyboard dumps a lot of information.
Notice: It has a bus number, and device number on that bus to identify were it is connected.

Then is has a unique ID number.  The first 4 indicate which manufacturer produced the device followed by a unique device number from that manufacturer.

```
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 03f0:0024 Hewlett-Packard KU-0316 Keyboard
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x03f0 Hewlett-Packard
  idProduct          0x0024 KU-0316 Keyboard
  bcdDevice            3.00
  iManufacturer           1 CHICONY
  iProduct                2 HP Basic USB Keyboard
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           34
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      65
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```